# Check statement for a loop only once

Tags: python, loops

Let’s say I have following simple code:

```
useText = True

for i in range(20):
    if useText:
        print("The square is "+ str(i**2))
    else:
        print(i**2)
```

I use the variable useText to control which way to print the squares. It doesn’t change while running the loop, so it seems inefficient to me to check it every time the loop runs. Is there any way to check useText only once, before the loop, and then always print out according to that result?

This question occurs to me quite often. In this simple case of course it doesn’t matter but I could imagine this leading to slower performance in more complex cases.

Comment: why not use two loops?

Comment: So how does useText change if it does change? is this example like a simple UI where useText is a toggle and the for loop is in a main run loop somewhere? I'm just trying to put this in a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general structure of your program is to loop through a sequence and print the result in some manner.

In code, this becomes

```
for i in range(20):
    print_square(i)
```

Before the loop runs, set `print_square` appropriately depending on the `useText` variable.

```
if useText:
    print_square = lambda x: print("The square is" + str(x**2))
else:
    print_square = lambda x: print(x**2)

for i in range(20):
    print_square(i)
```

This has the advantage of not repeating the loop structure or the check for `useText` and could easily be extended to support other methods of printing the results inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks. That seems the most elegant solution to me, because it avoids re-writing the whole loop again (if you were to make a for-loop inside the if-statement).

Answer (score 4):

The only difference that `useText` accomplishes here is the formatting string. So move that out of the loop.

```
fs = '{}'
if useText:
    fs = "The square is {}"

for i in range(20):
    print(fs.format(i**2))
```

(This *assumes* that `useText` doesn't change during the loop! In a multithreaded program that might not be true.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to change the value of `useText` inside the loop, you can move it outside of `for`:

```
if useText:
    for i in range(20):
        print("The square is "+ str(i**2))
else:
    for i in range(20):
        print(i**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can move `if` outside of `for` since you mentioned `useText` is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you write something like this, you're checking the condition, running code, moving to the next iteration, and repeating, checking the condition each time, because you're running the entire body of the `for` loop, including the `if` statement, on each iteration:

```
for i in a_list:
    if condition:
        code()
```

If you write something like this, with the `if` statement *inside* the `for` loop, you're checking the condition and running the entire `for` loop only if the condition is true:

```
if condition:
    for i in a_list:
        code()
```

I think you want the second one, because that one only checks the condition once, at the start. It does that because the `if` statement isn't inside the loop. Remember that everything inside the loop is run on each iteration.